# How to fix a view on top while scrolling a view in android

Tags: android

Hi I have views like this

```
<LinearLayout ...>
     <TextView../>
     <TextView../>
     <LinearLayout> ....</LinearLayout>   
     <ScrollView...>
        <LinearLayout ...>
             <TextView..."Title"/> ---> On Scrolling the view i want to fix this 
        textview on top once this view reach top. how can i do this..?        
             <LinearLayout>....</LinearLayout>
             <TextView../>
                :
                :
         </LinearLayout..>
     </ScrollView..>
```

On Scrolling the view i want to fix this 
            textview on top once this view reach top. how can i do this..?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what you want to do excatly ? please be more specific ? 
you mean you want to update the Top TextView when you reach some where in the listView ?

Comment: If you want fix that textview, you can move that field out of the scroll view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to fix some top layout .. then firstly you need to create that layout in separate layout then you need to include same in preferred layout.

You can include layout some thing like ..

```
 <include layout="@layout/your_prefered_layout_to_be_fixed"/>
```

Now most importantly apply scroll view with single child after including above layout.

Or simply you can apply some view in your preferred layout and then after use scroll view as mentioned above.

That's it .. You are good to go